# Unable to load images wrapped in svg

Tags: svg, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am working on a nuxt3 application.
some of the assets i am using needed to have an image wrapped inside the svg.
I am using svgloader plugin with nuxt3.

svg images with svg code are working fine while the ones with images load as a gradient.

example svg that do not work.

```
<svg width="742" height="762" viewBox="0 0 742 762" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_96_2309)">
        <circle cx="342" cy="206" r="9" fill="url(#paint11_linear_96_2309)" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <image id="image0_96_2309" width="608" height="1632" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAmAAAAZgCAYAAADZJPvDAAAACXBIWXMAABYlAAAWJQFJUiTwAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUABuH5SURBVHgB7P0JmGXnVd6Lv9+39xlrrurqqp5ndbe6NbXmWR5lS7aRJ9lATDAEmxBCIAkk2CS3uQESyD/xDQS4hDAGAghsPMqTbNmarKGlVkvd6nnu6urqmk/>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

here is how it rendered
[image]